# Next.JS SSG unable to bookmark slug paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, static-site-generation

I have a next js SSG exported application which runs in nginx. I have plans to move it to S3 soon. The issue I am facing is that the slug paths can not be bookmarked in a browser.

[image: Pages screenshot]

Internally the router works fine if I navigate using next router. But I want the users to bookmark this dynamic route.

For example https://hrm.com/groups/TECH and reach it directly.

I tried getStaticPaths but as the id is random and the number of ids can be close to 1000 in some cases. This might not be a good option for me.

fallback option can not be used as mentioned in the documentation that fallback true or blocking won't work for SSG

Comment: What you mean by unable to bookmark. Is it not rendering?

Comment: The bookmark working. I think there is some issue with your browser. Try bookmarking other url's.

Comment: If I save and hit this bookmarked url then the nginx returns 403 page

Comment: From the app I can navigate to the slug subpage without issues. But if I directly hit the url it fails with 403. Usually we configure the web server to route any sub paths via index page if there is an internal router involved. But I am not sure how to implement it in Next.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible (at least not easily).

The usual way is to use the next-server (i.e. `next build && next start`), which can build new pages at runtime. Otherwise your own server would need to build the HTML pages (in a next.js compatible way).

### Static files and routing

I understand that you used `next export` to generate static HTML pages, and you are serving them with nginx.

So all you have is a folder full of HTML files, and if you type a URL into the browsers address bar, the server has to match that URL to one of the HTML files.

A server might be pre-configured to know that e.g. the URL "/" should load "index.html", and you would see the a page, but if the server doesn't know that e.g. "/about" should load "about.html" it responds with `404`.

### Compiling HTML

The "dynamic route" in Next.js is just a file like `[id].js` (or in your case `[id]/index.js`), which needs to be compiled into a proper e.g. `123.html` file *(or directly into HTML content at runtime)*.

Without compiling, there is no HTML content. So *some* software has to create the HTML content at some point. E.g.:

- As soon as one of the pages is loaded, then the next.js scripts are loaded, and next.js can do the routing and compiling client-side (That's why the internal routing works).
- If you use the builtin next-server (i.e. `next build && next start`), the next-server has all the required routing set up.
- If you use your own server, you need to set up all the routing yourself.

### `getStaticPaths`

The next-server (`next start`) can create additional pages dynamically at runtime, so you can optionally specify only a few or none of the dynamic paths, and use the ["fallback"](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-true) option.

But `next export` (and `getStaticPaths`) only runs once at build time. Later only client-side code is executed, without filesystem access. So HTML files are only created at build time, all paths need to be specified at build time. ([`fallback: true` or `blocking` don't work](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features)), as you said.